# hide deps info in a chain of extra-deps

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal, haskell-stack

This is a Haskell stack package dependency configuration question.

1. I created a Haskell library `git:LibA`
2. I created another Haskell library `git:LibB` depending on `git:LibA`
3. I created a Haskell application `AppC` depending on `git:LibB`

To compile `LibB`, I need to specify `git:LibA` in `extra-deps` section of `LibB`'s `stack.yaml` with a commit checksum, which is reasonable.

To compile `AppC`, it seems that I need to specify both the following packages in `extra-deps` section of `AppC`'s `stack.yaml`

- `git:LibB` with a commit checksum
- `git:LibA` with a commit checksum

Is there any way to only specify `git:LibB` in `AppC` or configure `LibB` to hide `git:LibA` information to applications?

Motivation of the question: my current `AppC`'s `stack.yaml` is error-prone: if I update `LibA` and the commit checksum in `LibB` but forget to update the checksum in `AppC`, then I will not get the new `LibA` in `AppC`. In my opinion, the newer checksum of `LibB` should already contain the information of a newer `LibA`, and the developer of `AppC` should not need to update `LibA`'s checksum in `AppC` but only `LibB`'s checksum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, stack doesn't "see" the stack.yml of any dependencies, only their respective .cabal descriptors.

If you're building multiple internal packages you can just put them all under the same source tree and list them under the packages list in your `stack.yaml`:

```
packages:
- LibA
- LibB
- AppC
```

Note that that doesn't mean you all have to put them into the same VCS if you don't want to - you could use git submodules; Or you could even list git locations/hashes pretty much the same way you do with extra-deps directly.

That's of course not an option if your packages are supposed to be entirely independent, but at that point you'll probably want to look into a more structured solution like making [custom snapshots](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/custom_snapshot/) anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check custom snapshots, which seems to be the way to go (I need packages to be independent).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.  By design, `stack` uses only the `stack.yaml` of the project you are building.  It does not read or use any `stack.yaml` file which may exist in any of your dependencies.  One advantage of this design is that there is a single place to specify package versions.  Otherwise it's not clear how to handle different `stack.yaml` requesting different versions of the same package.

There are a couple of options if you want more convenience when developing these packages together, and don't care as much about keeping them independent.  You can specify relative paths in your `stack.yaml`, and always build with whatever versions you have locally checked out.  Or you can bring all three into a single VCS repo, and use the VCS to manage which changes to A should be linked to which in C.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. Is it easier to handle different versions if it is encoded in the library? E.g., libB-1.2 depends on libA-1.5.1, libB-1.3 depends on libA-1.7.1 If such information is not provided by `stack.yaml` of libB, it is pretty hard for `AppC` to know this dependency. Maybe this is the key functionality of  `stackage` resolvers since packages do not specify their dependency versions.

Comment: The purpose of a `stack.yaml` file is to specify exact versions for all Haskell dependencies.  `stack solver` will generate a `stack.yaml` using the bounds provided in `.cabal` files as guidance.  A stackage snapshot that includes all the libraries you need is another way to save time in version selection.  In general, libraries work with multiple versions of their dependencies.  Only at the application level do we know the full set of dependencies, to pick the latest compatible set.

Comment: I see. So the current model is to let `AppC` developer to pick up all dependency versions hierarchically. With a `stack resolver`, actually the developer only needs to pick up the versions (or even no version needed) for depth one, and a snapshot contains all latest consistent packages. I would like to have this for my libraries, so I will look at custom snapshots.